# Creating progress bar for uploading files using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, uploading

I'd like to create a progress bar for uploading files using jquery and ajax. so i wrote following jquery code.

```
function updateProgress(evt)
{
    // evt is an ProgressEvent.
    if (evt.lengthComputable)
    {
        var percentLoaded = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
        // Increase the progress bar length.
        $(".progress > div").css(
        {
            width: percentLoaded + '%'
        });

    }
}

$.ajax(
{
    url: 'assets/php/upload.php?action=uploadFiles',
    type: 'POST',
    data: newFormData,
    cache: false,
    xhr: function ()
    {
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload)
        {
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});
```

But the problem is the progress bar will be 100% in a second while uploading file has not finished yet. what is wrong with my code?

Thank you,

Alireza

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's something related with your style... don't know since I can't see all your code. Try with the following. It's working, but imperceptible with small files. You can use a breakpoint or upload a really huge file to be able to see it. source: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

```
<style>
  #progress_bar {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    clear: both;
    opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  }
  #progress_bar.loading {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  #progress_bar .percent {
    background-color: #99ccff;
    height: auto;
    width: 0;
  }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />
<button onclick="abortRead();">Cancel read</button>
<div id="progress_bar"><div class="percent">0%</div></div>

<script>
  var reader;
  var progress = document.querySelector('.percent');

  function abortRead() {
    reader.abort();
  }

  function errorHandler(evt) {
    switch(evt.target.error.code) {
      case evt.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
        alert('File Not Found!');
        break;
      case evt.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
        alert('File is not readable');
        break;
      case evt.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
        break; // noop
      default:
        alert('An error occurred reading this file.');
    };
  }

  function updateProgress(evt) {
    // evt is an ProgressEvent.
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentLoaded = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
      // Increase the progress bar length.
      if (percentLoaded < 100) {
        progress.style.width = percentLoaded + '%';
        progress.textContent = percentLoaded + '%';
      }
    }
  }

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    // Reset progress indicator on new file selection.
    progress.style.width = '0%';
    progress.textContent = '0%';

    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = errorHandler;
    reader.onprogress = updateProgress;
    reader.onabort = function(e) {
      alert('File read cancelled');
    };
    reader.onloadstart = function(e) {
      document.getElementById('progress_bar').className = 'loading';
    };
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      // Ensure that the progress bar displays 100% at the end.
      progress.style.width = '100%';
      progress.textContent = '100%';
      setTimeout("document.getElementById('progress_bar').className='';", 2000);
    }

    // Read in the image file as a binary string.
    reader.readAsBinaryString(evt.target.files[0]);
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```